# Which one is correct - "gained through doing" or "gained by doing"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I want to mention in my resume that I have enough knowledge in flood frequency analysis :

> Sound knowledge of flood frequency analysis which I gained through/by doing Masters' thesis in this field.

Should I use through or by?
Is my sentence grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both **through** and **by** carry the meaning "by means of".

> He got results through hard work
>
> He ​learned ​Spanish by watching Spanish movies

**through** sounds slightly more formal. **doing** sounds rather informal: you could omit it with **through**, but not with **by**.

> ...which I gained through a Masters' thesis in this field.

Comment: I agree with the main part of this answer, but I think that the last example is unhelpful. You can't say "I got my car by a friend", and the meaning is not simply "by means of", but something like "by means of my friend's connections".

Comment: @ColinFine, I was trying to demonstrate that it was appropriate to use **through** without the gerund, but the supporting text was not well worded. Best to omit it altogether.